# Selenium in Chrome browser shows Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start

Tags: java, selenium

Hell0,
I am new to Selenium. I have installed selenium and was writing my first code. I am getting the following error

---

Starting ChromeDriver 89.0.4389.23 (61b08ee2c50024bab004e48d2b1b083cdbdac579-refs/branch-heads/4389@{#294}) on port 46362
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-LCJO8BB', ip: '192.168.1.8', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:181)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
at seleniumPackage.SeleniumClass.main(SeleniumClass.java:12)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:46362/status] to be available after 20005 ms
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
... 10 more

My Code

---

`````
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class SeleniumClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Selenium\\Jars and Drivers\\Drivers\\Chrome\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "F:/Selenium/Jars and Drivers/Drivers/Firefox/geckodriver-v0.29.0-win64/geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }

}````

Could you please assist here.

Thanks,
Jisha
`````

Answer (score 0):

```
code is correct. added code for time out exception. implicitlyWait added
public class SeleniumClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\\\Drivers\\\\chromedriver.exe");
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "F:/Selenium/Jars and Drivers/Drivers/Firefox/geckodriver-v0.29.0-win64/geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello @user3636689, I tried to add impicit wait too. Yet I am getting the same error. additional information, JDK version - jdk-15.0.2_windows-x64_bin, selenium - selenium-java-3.141.59

Answer (score 0):

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

try - I downloaded latest stable version and it worked.

Comment: It worked for me as well. The issue is resolved.